# Issue with Tax Function (If/Else statements)

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with my function. When I enter calculateTaxRate(10000, "joint") it is not giving me the correct answer of 10%. It is returning "Better call an accountant". I'm not sure why that is still happening. Any help in explaining this to me would be greatly appreciated.

```
function calculateTaxRate(salary, status) {
if (status !== ("single" || "joint") || (salary > 74900)) {
    return "Better call an accountant";
} else if (status == "single") {
    if (salary <= 9225) {
        return "10%";
    } else if (9226 <= salary && salary <= 37450) {
        return "15%";
    } else {
        return "25%";
    }
}
if (status == "joint") {
    if (0 <= salary && salary <= 18450) {
        return "10%";
    } else if (18451 <= salary && salary <= $74, 900) {
        return "15%";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `status !== ("single" || "joint")` doesn't do what you think - you need to learn javascript syntax - it's not invalid, but you're essentially checking `if status !== "single"` only

Answer (score 2):

The code `("single" || "joint")` evaluates to "single".

An OR condition written as `expr1 || expr2` returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. For example:

```
true || false = true
false || true = true
"Single" || false = "Single"
false || "Joint" = "Joint"
```

The IF condition should be written as:

```
if ((status !== "single" && status !== "joint") || (salary > 74900)) {
```

See Mozilla Developer documentation on [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)